# PHPSTORM 8 support For CodeIgniter using Google App Engine SDK

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, google-app-engine, phpstorm

Using **Phpstorm** **Google App Engine** interpreter the **Code Igniter** is working fine when we run the index page.

It correctly take the default controller php file and then loading the particular view which is called in default controller inside index function.

But in a similar way, **calling the controller via ajax is not working**,

it throws below error:

```
    error in getting
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"<!doctype html><title>404 Not Found</title><h1 style=\"text-align: center\">404 Not Found</h1><hr/><p style=\"text-align: center\">PhpStorm 8.0.3</p>","status":404,"statusText":"Not Found"}
```

https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/using-framework-model-view-ontroller.html

As per the above link,phpstorm-mvc can be configured only for **symphony** and **yii**.

Then how to configure the CI framework integration in phpstorm or else without configuring, how to  make function the ajax function which is used in all view file to call the relevant controller function.

**Example:**

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + '/index.php/controllerFileName/functionName...,
                success: function(data){},
                error(data){
                                            //ERROR is thrown at this stage
                       }
                });
```

Now we are currently using ajax as mentioned above, which is working perfectly via xampp (running in localhost). We need to use this interpreter for our project. So,how to configure the **base url** in this case.

Pls  any hint will be a help for us to run **Google App Engine SDK** with **Code Igniter integration in PHPSTORM**